# LoganSquare - parsing inner json

Tags: android, json, logan-square

I am trying to use LoganSquare to parse json with retrofit. One of the fields of my custom class is a JSONObject:

```
@JsonField(name = "Result", typeConverter = JSONAdapter.class)
public JSONObject result;
```

But I'm not sure how I am supposed to parse that inner JSON. This is what i tried so far without any luck:

```
public class JSONAdapter implements TypeConverter<JSONObject> {
    @Override
    public JSONObject parse(JsonParser jsonParser) throws IOException {
        try {
            String valueAsString = jsonParser.getValueAsString("{}");
            return new JSONObject(valueAsString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(JSONObject object, String fieldName, boolean writeFieldNameForObject, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

`jsonParser.getValueAsString()` is returning null. Am I missing something?